# Why does \the\day not work in my macro?

Tags: tex-core, datetime

(TeX-Code!)

I have defined a TeX-macro to compare date and time values. Everything works well, until I put in `\the\day`, to call the current value of it. Can someone imagine, why this works with all the date and time functions, except of `\the\day` ?

```
    %transformations of \time
\newcount\hour  %
\newcount\hours  %
\newcount\minutes  %
\hour=\time \divide\hour by 60 
\minutes=\time
\hours=\hour \multiply\hours by 60 
\advance \minutes by -\hours
%end transformations of \time
%begin  definitions of caldate
\newcount\fromcalyear %% 
\newcount\fromcalmonth %%
\newcount\fromcalday %%
\newcount\fromcalhour %%
\newcount\fromcalminutes %%
\newcount\tocalyear %% 
\newcount\tocalmonth %%
\newcount\tocalday %%
\newcount\tocalhour %%
\newcount\tocalminutes %%
\newcount\rescalyear %% 
\newcount\rescalmonth %%
\newcount\rescalday %%
\newcount\rescalhour %%
\newcount\rescalminutes %%
\def\fromcaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\global\fromcalyear=#1 %
\global\fromcalmonth=#2 %
\global\fromcalday=#3 %
\global\fromcalhour=#4 %
\global\fromcalminutes=#5 %
\ \the\fromcalyear-\ifnum\fromcalmonth<10
0\fi\the\fromcalmonth-\ifnum\fromcalday<10
0\fi\the\fromcalday\ \ifnum\fromcalhour<10
0\fi\the\fromcalhour:\ifnum\fromcalminutes<10 0\fi\the\fromcalminutes
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\tocaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
\global\tocalyear=#1 %
\global\tocalmonth=#2 %
\global\tocalday=#3 %
\global\tocalhour=#4 %
\global\tocalminutes=#5\ % 
\the\tocalyear-\ifnum\tocalmonth<10
0\fi\the\tocalmonth-\ifnum\tocalday<10
0\fi\the\tocalday\ \ifnum\tocalhour<10
0\fi\the\tocalhour:\ifnum\tocalminutes<10 0\fi\the\tocalminutes}
\def\rescaldate{
\global\rescalyear=\the\fromcalyear %
\global\rescalmonth=\fromcalmonth %
\global\rescalday=\fromcalday %
\global\rescalhour=\fromcalhour %
\global\rescalminutes=\fromcalminutes %
\advance\rescalyear by -\tocalyear %
\global\advance\rescalmonth by -\tocalmonth  %
\global\advance\rescalday by -\tocalday   %
\global\advance\rescalhour by -\tocalhour   %
\global\advance\rescalminutes by -\tocalminutes   %
\vskip0.1\baselineskip}% 
\def\rescaldatetime{\rescaldate (\the\rescalyear)-(\the\rescalmonth)-(\the\rescalday)\ (\the\rescalhour):(\the\rescalminutes)}
%end definitions of caldate
Here, the day is displayed: {\bf \the\day}
\vskip1\baselineskip
Below, it works without calling the day by function

From Date: \fromcaldate[\the\year-\the\month-11 \the\hour:\the\minutes]
To Date: \tocaldate[2012-11-05 04:16]

Res Date: \rescaldatetime
\vskip1\baselineskip

Below, it does not work with calling the day by function (outcommented)

%Fromdate: \fromcaldate[\the\year-\the\month-\the\day 13:00]
%Fromdate: \fromcaldate[\the\year-\the\month-\the\day \the\hour:\the\minutes]
%Todate: \tocaldate[\the\year-\the\month-\the\day \the\hour:\the\minutes]

%Resdate: \rescaldatetime

\bye
```

Answer (score 10):

You have

```
\def\tocaldate[#1-#2-#3 #4:#5]{%
```

so there has to be a space token after `#3`

```
Fromdate: \fromcaldate[\the\year-\the\month-\the\day 13:00]
```

there is no space token before `13` in the above as the space in the file is absorbed while tokenising `\day`.

Use

```
Fromdate: \fromcaldate[\the\year-\the\month-{\the\day} 13:00]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I use grouping for all the datetime values to be consistent? Do you have an idea, why it works with all the other values, but not for the day value? May a {} after `\the\day` work out as well?

Comment: @M.Borck-Elsner the other values are delimited by `-` and there is a `-` token. `{}` at the end may accidentally work (it does) but that passes `{}` as part of the argument so whether it works or not depends on the details of the definition in your macro. conversely `{\the\day} ` the entire argument is surrounded by `{..}` so TeX strips off the braces and does not pass them to the macro, so you can know that works without looking at the details of the code

Comment: May be redefining it to `\fromcaldate[#1-#2-#3;#4:#5]` (or whatever) with a delimiting token different than a space.

Comment: I have changed the delimiters to `\fromcaldate[#1-#2-#3-#4:#5]` because it doesn't really matter much. I would have liked to keep the format, but in the output, it makes no difference.